# Reading data from multiple CSV files and adding each file to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following code from multiple CSV files:

```
import pandas as p
import csv 
csv_list=['interview1.csv', 'interview2.csv', ...]
for itw in csv_list:
    df = p.read_csv(itw)
    df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

Right now it adds everything to the new CSV file in one long column. How would I move to a new column after each CSV file is read in order to have multiple columns in the one output file? Essentially I would like each input file to be one column in a single output file.

All csv files have multiple columns, but I can add `usecols = [6]` for them to get the column I need. All CSVs have the same number of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a list of dataframes, and then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them on `axis=1`
- Use a list comprehension to create the list of dataframes

  - The entire thing can be combined into one line, but multiple lines have been used for clarity.

    - `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(itw) for itw in csv_list], axis=1)`
- Rows will be filled with `NaN`, for columns of shorter lengths.
- Also see [Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) and [How to create a dict of dataframes from multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63887002/7758804) for more options.

```py
import pandas as pd

# list of all files
csv_list=['interview1.csv', 'interview2.csv']

# create list of dataframes
df_list = [pd.read_csv(itw) for itw in csv_list]
    
# combine all the dataframes
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

# save
df.to_csv('combined_files.csv', index=False)

# display(df)
  col  col  col2
0   1    1  33.0
1   2   23  44.0
2   2   24  55.0
3   3   3t  66.0
4   3    3  77.0
5   4   45  88.0
6   5  NaN   NaN
7   5  NaN   NaN
8   6  NaN   NaN
```

### list comprehension as a for loop

```py
df_list = list()
for itw in csv_list:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(itw))
```

### Sample CSV files

#### `interview1.csv`

```py
col
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
5
6
```

#### `interview2.csv`

```py
col,col2
1,33
23,44
24,55
3t,66
3,77
45,88
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datasets have a common column (in this example called 'ID'), you can use pd.merge():

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
csv_list=['interview2.csv', 'interview3.csv', ...]
merged = pd.read_csv('interview1.csv')
for itw in csv_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(itw)
    merged = pd.merge(left=merged, right=df, on='ID', how='outer')
merged.to_csv('out.csv')
```