# How to create a dict of dataframes from multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pathlib

I am loading a csv file in pandas as

```
premier10 = pd.read_csv('./premier_league/pl_09_10.csv')
```

However, I have 20+ csv files, which I was hoping to load as separate dfs (one df per csv) using a loop and predefined names, something similar to:

```
import pandas as pd
file_names = ['pl_09_10.csv','pl_10_11.csv']
names = ['premier10','premier11']
for i in range (0,len(file_names)):
     names[i] = pd.read_csv('./premier_league/{}'.format(file_names[i]))
```

(Note, here I provide only two csv files as example) Unfortunately, this doesn't work (no error messages, but the the pd dfs don't exist).

Any tips/links to previous questions would be greatly appreciated as I haven't found anything similar on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to set a Path, `p`, to the files
2. Use the [`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method to find the files matching the pattern
3. Create a dataframe with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

   - Use a dict comprehension to create a dict of dataframes, where each file will have its own key-value pair.

     - Use the dict like any other dict; the keys are the file names and the values are the dataframes.
   - Alternatively, use a list comprehension with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to create a single dataframe from all the files.

- In the `for-loop` in the OP, objects (variables) may not be created in that way (e.g. `names[i]`).

  - This is equivalent to `'premier10' = pd.read_csv(...)`, where `'premier10'` is a `str` type.
- See [Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) to create a single `DataFrame` and add a column name with the source file name.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# set the path to the files
p = Path('some_path/premier_league')  

# create a list of the files matching the pattern
files = list(p.glob(f'pl_*.csv'))

# creates a dict of dataframes, where each file has a separate dataframe
df_dict = {f.stem: pd.read_csv(f) for f in files}  

# alternative, creates 1 dataframe from all files
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])
```

Answer (score 0):

`names = ['premier10','premier11']` does not create a dictionary but a list. Simply replace it with `names = dict()` or replace `names = ['premier10','premier11']` by `names.append(['premier10','premier11'])`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
#create a variable and look through contents of the directory 
files=[f for f in os.listdir("./your_directory") if f.endswith('.csv')]

#Initalize an empty data frame
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

#iterate through files and their contents, then concatenate their data into the data frame initialized above
for file in files:
   df = pd.read_csv('./your_directory' + file)
   all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df])

#Call the new data frame and verify that contents were transferred
all_data.head()
```